# What's the intention behind Idris' `BorrowedType`?

Tags: idris, linear-types, uniqueness-typing

In idris, there's a universe called `UniqueType` the values of the types in which can only be used once. As far as I know, it can be used to write high-performance code.
But the fact that a value can only be used once is usually too limited, so there's a way to *borrow* a value instead of consuming it:

```
data Borrowed : UniqueType -> BorrowedType where ...
```

The `Borrowed` data type is defined as above in Idris. Why doesn't it simply return `Type` but introduce another universe of types (`BorrowedType`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As the documentation explains](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/uniqueness-types.html), there are restriction on `BorrowedType`-typed `Borrowed` values:

> Unlike a unique value, a borrowed value may be referred to as many times as desired. However, there is a restriction on how a borrowed value can be used. After all, much like a library book or your neighbour’s lawnmower, if a function borrows a value it is expected to return it in exactly the condition in which it was received!
>
> The restriction is that when a `Borrowed` type is matched, any pattern variables under the `Read` which have a unique type may not be referred to at all on the right hand side (unless they are themselves lent to another function).

This restriction (and `lend`'s leniency) is implemented by special typing rules in the typechecker. Those rules need something to apply to, which is why `BorrowedType` has to be a separate kind than regular `Type` (for which there aren't special `lend`/`Read` typing rules).